# AJAX: jQuery DataTables (Server Side) not getting any request (GET or POST) data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm attempting to print a simple DataTables which I want to update when I use the search/filters on any column (or the "entire table" one in the top right of the page).  When I click on a column header (to sort) the request goes through (though the page still says "processing" indefinitely).  When I type anything into a filter it says "processing" indefinitely, but no request is passed to the server.

Here are the scripts:

client.php

```
<!-- jQuery and DataTables JS files, including CSS, are included here -->
<table id="employee-table" class="table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#employee-table").dataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "datatable.php",
            type: 'POST'
        }
    }).columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
        aoColumns: [
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

datatable.php

```
file_put_contents("debug.txt", $_REQUEST);

echo '{
"draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 3,
"recordsFiltered": 3,
"data": [
    [
        "Angelica",
        "Ramos",
        "1986-01-01"
    ],
    [
        "Ashton",
        "Cox",
        "1987-01-01"
    ],
    [
        "Test",
        "Third",
        "1989-01-01"
    ]
]
}';
```

As you can see, all I do on the server-side script is print all requested data to a file so I can check it.  The problem is, no matter what I type into the filter boxes no request data goes through.  Here is a visual:

[image: Notice the search for 198 in the top-right corner and the ever persisting "Processing..." on the screen]

Here is the output to the debug.txt.  NOTE that this is what is loaded into the file on the initial load of client.php, it is NOT changed when you type anything into any search boxes:

```
Array
(
[draw] => 1
[columns] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [data] => 0
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [data] => 1
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [data] => 2
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

    )

[order] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [column] => 0
                [dir] => asc
            )

    )

[start] => 0
[length] => 10
[search] => Array
    (
        [value] => 
        [regex] => false
    )

)
```

What am I missing to get the filters to work correctly?  I assume my client-side DataTables JavaScript is misconfigured, but I can't tell how.  My searches seem to be only pulling up "legacy" DataTables solutions instead of the simplified newer version they have.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

**client.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#employee-table').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bRedraw": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "datatable.php",
            "aoColumns": [
                {"mDataProp": "first"},
                {"mDataProp": "last"},
                {"mDataProp": "dob"},
            ],
            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]]
    });
});
```

**datatable.php**

Please check the below link and configure your database setting in the code provided by datatable.

[Server Side Code](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql)

Comment: That JavaScript results in the following alert: `DataTables warning: table-id=employee-table - Requested unknown parameter "first" for row 0.  For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`  Also the entire of debug.txt is just an empty array, meaning no data (at all) is submitting this way, over GET nor POST.